# WordPress plugin admin page jQuery not defined

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've made a WordPress plugin with an admin page. 
But if I use jQuery on my admin page it says that jQuery is not defined.

```
function addAcScripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addAcScripts');
```

On my test site its working fine, but on another test site on my localhost its not working.

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

How do I include jQuery on the admin page?

Comment: You never need to enqueue jQuery in wordpress, there must be some other problem .

Comment: 1) Check the source code of the admin page locally, can you see the jQuery included file?  2) (if yes to 1) is the path the correct path for the localhost domain? 3) are there any other javascript errors in the console when yo uload the page or try to do something?

Comment: When I load the page there a no errors. But when I click a button that triggers my function, it gives me that error. In the pagesource I see that it includes some jQuery files.

Comment: First instead of using`wp_enqueue_scripts` use `admin_enqueue_scripts`, because the first one only enqueues scripts outside the admin dashboard. Also check the path to your jquery file or cdn.

Also as Prafulla said, jquery is already added to wordpress admin.